# Pandas: remove duplicate lists containing same elements

Tags: python, pandas, networkx, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have some lists like this form:

```
master_list = [[2,3,5], [3,2,5], [2,3], [2], [3], [5, 6], [5,9], [5,6,9], [9,5,6]]
```

each sub_list in the master_list is a read of a row from an excel. The number in the list indicates the route_id.

What I want is to obtain the unique routes combination, which is linked to a truck assignment.

So the desired output is:

```
[[2,3,5], [9,5,6]]
```

the sequence of the number in the sub_list does not matter, but have to be the one contains all route_id not partial.

So I could do:

```
truck_1 = [2,3,5]
truck_2 = [9,5,6]
```

appreciate for help

Comment: `set(frozenset(i) for i in master_list)`

Comment: I dont quite understand how to apply your method. Could you explain a little more?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all possible route combinations and check if each combination contains all items from the `master_list`:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

all_items = set(chain.from_iterable(master_list))
combos = chain.from_iterable(combinations(master_list, i) for i in range(len(master_list)))

result = []
max_len = len(master_list)

for c in combos:
    if set(chain.from_iterable(c)) == all_items and len(c) <= max_len:
        max_len = len(c)
        result.append(c)
```

Comment: yes, I think in the same way. I wonder if there are more efficient approach as this is computationally expensive for a big dataframe

Comment: @Jack You can use the graph theory and the package `networkx`. But I don't know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: this method takes too much time for only 920 rows, which become impractical.

Comment: @Jack Try to google, I think there are already some algorithms for this problem.